# post to actionrequest from an anchor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback

I have the following;

```
    <% using(Html.BeginForm("GetRecommendedProducts", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("QuickQuote", Model.quickQuote); %>
        <div class="But brown" style="float:left;">
            <a href="." onclick="$.unblockUI(); return false;">Close</a>
        </div>
        <div class="But green" style="">
            <a href="." onclick="this.form.submit(); return false;">Go</a>
        </div>
    <%} %>
```

When I click the anchor I do not get a post to my action.  I know this should be possible so what am I doing wrong?

The partial view only contains fields and not another BeginForm or anything like that.

If I use a submit button it works ok but I can't use a submit button I need to use an anchor.

Comment: Why can't you use a submit button?, the scenario you describe is exactly what a submit button was intended for. Excessive use of CSS can make a button look like almost anything. (I assume you are happy to make your button inaccessible for those without javascript)

Comment: There is a bunch of css surrounding the link which makes it look like a stylised button and my hands on this are tied.  I know I can use a submit button and css the heck out of it but it still doesn't look quite right and there are multiple buttons and they all need to look the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the id of the form element and then call submit on that:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('the_form').submit(); return false;">Go</a>
```

or if using jQuery:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#the_form').submit(); return false;">Go</a>
```

So `the_form` is the id of the form tag that is created from the `Html.BeginForm("GetRecommendedProducts", "Home", FormMethod.Post)` line.